# How to filter an array from an object

Tags: javascript, typescript

i have a check box that i populate as follows

```
<div repeat.for="list of Items" change.delegate="getClicked()"  >

<md-checkbox  checked.bind="List" model.bind="list" >${list.name}</md-checkbox>
</div>
```

i have another list in my ts page that returns all the items and is stored as follows

```
getClicked()
{
let result= this.ItemList  // this object contains a list of items
}
```

what i wanted to achieve is if i click on the checkbox i want to get the id and filter it on the ItemList object to only return that items.

This is what i have

```
getClicked() {
        
        let Id = this.List.map(x=> x.id);
        let result = this.ItemList.filter(x => x.ItemId === Id)
}

Items=[{ id: 11125e, name:"coke" },
        { id: 11125e,name:"juice" },
        { id: 33e4,name:"chips" }]
```

the problem i am having is that my result is always returned as [] empty.

this is what is happening when i get the id for example

```
let Id = this.List.map(x=> x.id);// id returned["11125e"]
            let result = this.ItemList.filter(x => x.ItemId ===["11125e"] ) // id gets passed with [] around it
```

but if i have to manualy test and i do this with out the [] it works and i get a result back

```
let result = this.ItemList.filter(x => x.ItemId ==="11125e" )
```

so my question is how do i get `this.List.map(x=> x.id);// id returned["11125e"] to be "11125e"`

Comment: Just use `find` instead of `map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method creates a **new array** populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array

What you're looking for is `find`

> The [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method returns the **value** of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function.

---

```
let result = this.ItemList.find(x => x.ItemId ==="11125e")
```